# VBA writing to file is rounding numeric values - how to prevent?

Tags: excel, vba

In the below code I am having problems making sure the file writer does not round my number off to a certain number of decimal places. I need to use a variant because sometimes the value is string and at other times it is a number.

How can I force it to write exactly what the variable is? For example the below code might show 0.00038 and I want to show the exact value.

```
Dim MyFile1 As Variant
Dim MyNumber as Variant

MyFile0 = "C:/myfile.csv"
fnum0 = FreeFile()
Open MyFile0 For Output As fnum0

MyNumber = 0.0003759656

Print #fnum0, MyNumber
```

Comment: Ummm, It is not rounding off for me. I opened the `myfile.csv` in Notepad and i could see the complete number. However if I open the file in Excel then the number is displaed in Scientific notation but in the formula bar, I can still see the complete number.

Comment: I have the same outcome of Siddhart Rout. Are you sure you aren't opening the `myfile.csv` back in Excel (it'll show the value rounded)?

Comment: csv file saves it as is. if you open the file back in excel you may want to use a template that formats your cells as Text, or use schema.ini

Comment: @Everyone this was just an example. I have csv files where I am comparing two "sources" and showing where there is a mismatch. In the VBA it is detecting val1 <> val2 and then in the csv file it outputs val1 and val2, but they look the same. If I click in the formula bar the numbers are exactly the same (e.g. 0.0003). I presumed the way I was writing the variables was losing information?

Comment: [read on vbtextcompare, vbbinarycompare](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/9s233cfc(v=vs.90).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Your code is fine. The issue is with excel. When opening a CSV in excel, including thru VBA, excel detirmines what a cell is. Typically, if it lloks like a number with more then 5 characters it will express it in Scientific notation or rounded to 5 places.

Note sure what you are doing with the CSV file before or where you are getting it from, but here are some options to prevent excel from changing your data:

In VBA use the Workbook.OpenText command to open the CSV with either:

-the all excel cells as text*

-the column stored number with so many decimal places
     (note a max of 30 decimal places apply)

-a particular column store as text.

--A full list of option syntax here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb22351(v=office.12).aspx

You may also import your CSV into an excel spreadsheet, it will give you the option to choose data type for each column. Then run the VBA against the excel file.

If you are not doing formulations in excel, I would recomend storing the number as a text string. VBA automatically converts strings of numbers into numeric values when needed.

Comment: Do you mean when opening the CSV to write the data to?

Answer (score 1):

It's likely that you're experiencing floating point errors. They are are very small errors that occur when numbers are converted from/to base 10 (human) to/from base 2 (computer). For your purposes, you need to determine what it means that two values are not equal. It's not just `val1 <> val2` because that won't account for the tiny errors. If you're dealing with money, for instance, you probably don't care about anything less than a penny. So you might determine inequality as `ABS(val1 - val2) > .001`.  You just need to determine what your tolerance for equality is and compare to that standard.

Answer (score 0):

It may be that your number is not being stored as a number in vba, and when you write it Excel converts it.   Say you're number is 1.789 and you write it to a cell that is formatted as 'GENERAL'.  Excel will write 1.79 (and think that's the number, not even a formatting issue).

What I've discovered, is if you convert the number to a decimal first CDEC(YOURNUMBER), it will write it correctly.   For good measure, I also verify that the cell is '.NUMBERFORMAT = "GENERAL'